# Qemu translator raises a FATAL: kernel too old

Tags: qemu

I build qemu from sources with targets `arm-softmmu` and `arm-linux-user`. I have a simple binary compiled for arm but when i launch it with qemu translator i get a `FATAL: kernel is too old`. I'm running qemu on a x86_64 host with kernel 2.6.32. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error because I was running:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel vmlinux -initrd rootfs.cpio.gz
```

while it should be:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel bzImage -initrd rootfs.cpio.gz
```

where `bzImage` is located at `arch/x86/boot/bzImage`.

This error happens because glibc has a kernel version check to avoid incompatibilities. The message comes from glibc, not QEMU.

Also in user mode, you might try to work around the problem with the `-r` option which artificially sets a different `uname` kernel version:

```
qemu-x86_64 -r 4.18
```

This might work, but of course, is not necessarily reliable, as QEMU presumably sets its version more or less correctly based on the syscalls/system interfaces it implements, so your program could through glibc rely on some interface that is not yet implemented.

The correct solution is to get a cross-compiler that more closely matches what QEMU userland gives you.

Answer (score 1):

The c library you used to build the binary is much more newer that your *guest* kernel.

Comment: So you mean that the c library statically linked into the ARM binary is newer than the c library on the x86 system where the ARM binary is failing to execute? In my case, the linked in ARM libc library is 2.18 and the x86 system library I'm running it on has libc 2.19 (and previously 2.17), and both are using gcc 4.8.x, so there must be other causes.