# C++ binary gives error FATAL: kernel too old

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel

I did compiled a C++ statically linked program on Archlinux and try to run it on CentOS 7 and I got

```
FATAL: kernel too old
```

Same happen if I use clang.

However, on same Archlinux I have container with CentOS 7. It uses same kernel, but older version of gcc.

If I do so, I do not get such message, so problem not seems to be with the kernel.

Is there a way to compile it with some option so it will run on CentOS 7?

#### Versions:

```
__Archlinux__: (binary say: kernel too old)

    Kernel 5.14.16
    gcc version 11.1.0
    clang version 13.0.0

__Archlinux container__: (binary works)

    Kernel 5.14.16
    gcc version 7.3.1

__CentOS 7__

    kernel 3.10.0
```

Comment: `It uses same kernel, but older version of gcc.` but newer C standard library `problem not seems to be with the kernel.` You are using kernel 3.10.0. This is the real problem. The _oldest_ LTS is 4.4.

Comment: this is what I suspected. Any easy way to use different C standard library?

Comment: Can you build the program in a CentOS 7 container?

Comment: Generally yes. But else will be easier - compile once, run everywhere.

Comment: The runtime error message comes from libc (glibc). Most distros configure the build of libc to only be compatible with kernels from a specified minimal kernel version onwards. For glibc, that is set using its `configure` script's `--enable-kernel=VERSION` option. It is possible to build `glibc` without that option in order to enable support for all kernel versions (or at least all kernel versions supported for the target architecture), but distros do not tend to do that.

Comment: If you want to "compile once, run everywhere", then you need to build for the lowest common denominator - generally the oldest system you wish to run it on!

Comment: BTW, under the "Versions:" heading in your question, is the "(binary say: kernel too old)" comment attached to the wrong OS?

Comment: @IanAbbott yes, "binary say: kernel too old" means CentOS 7 say this when use the program.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477267/qemu-translator-raises-a-fatal-kernel-too-old/30383260#30383260